# is there a mechanism for capturing and comparing mvc-mini-profiler results?

Tags: servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

The mvc-mini-profiler is a handy tool.  ServiceStack has a forked version for use in services.  I was thinking it would be dandy to capture the outputs of runs before and after a code change and compare the results.

I figure the steps are:

1. log the results to a data store or file instead of returning them in the result
2. compare the output of the various nodes
3. show the results side-by-side with diffs highlighted
4. bonus: configure tolerances for diff in amount of time spent in different areas.  i.e. i may not care if time in sql varies by 300ms.

I did a quick search and didn't see anything.

Thanks,
Drew